# what is the best way for Using SignalR in a webform project with c#?

Tags: c#, webforms, signalr

I wanna have notifications in my project that is in Asp.net WebForms  C# ..
is using SignalR with Kendo Framewrok well?

Comment: please read [How To As Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Webform Project Is Dead, Forget it.

Comment: i use mvc in my projects but in this case i have no other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Read [Adding SignalR to an ASP.NET WebForms Project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/526876/addingplussignalrplustoplusanplusasp-netpluswebfor)
Post in Code Project that Implements SingnalR On ASP.NET WebForm.

Comment: thanks. but i want to know is kendo  a good tools to use for this case  or not

Comment: @AmirhoseinAraghi  No, Is not Good tools.